# Problemas al posicionar menú y pie de página

Tags: html, css

Estoy empezando con css y tengo un problema, adjunto la imagen de este:

[image: Problema css]

Como se puede observar, tanto el footer como el aside no se vuelve a colocar abajo de la página y el resto de contenido se descoloca todo.

Adjunto los códigos:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: #D8D8D8;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #151515;
  color: white;
}

#logo {
  display: inline-block;
}

#logo-img {
  display: inline-block;
}

#logo-img img {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#logo-name {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#fecha {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 53%;
}

#account {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

aside {
  background-color: #151515;
  color: white;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.menu-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 15px;
}

.menu-list:hover {
  background-color: #2E2E2E;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-list-dashboard {
  background-color: #2E2E2E;
}

.menu-list a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#summary-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 150px;
}

#container-title,
#container-title {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  /*250px;*/
}

.card-name {
  background-color: #151515;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 3px solid orange;
}

.card-info {
  background-color: #2E2E2E;
  color: white;
}

.card-info>p {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.card-more-info {
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
}

.card-more-info p {
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.img-up,
.img-down {
  width: 15px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #151515;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <title>WebSAT - Dashboard</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div id="logo">
      <div id="logo-img">
        <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Logo empresa" />
      </div>
      <div id="logo-name">
        <p>WebSAT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="fecha">
      <p>06-JUL-2019</p>
    </div>
    <div id="account">
      <div id="account-menu">
        <p>Usuario</p>
      </div>
      <div id="account-menu-arrow">

      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <aside>
    <ul id="menu-list-container">
      <li class="menu-list menu-list-dashboard"><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li class="menu-list menu-list-clients"><a href="#">Clientes</a></li>
      <li class="menu-list menu-list-products"><a href="#">Productos</a></li>
      <li class="menu-list menu-list-services"><a href="#">Servicios</a></li>
      <li class="menu-list menu-list-workshop"><a href="#">Taller</a></li>
      <li class="menu-list menu-sales"><a href="#">Ventas</a></li>
      <li class="menu-list menu-list-repairs"><a href="#">Reparaciones</a></li>
      <li class="menu-list menu-list-expenses"><a href="#">Gastos</a></li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
  <section>
    <div id="summary-container">
      <div id="card-container">
        <div id="container-title">
          <h2>Resumen</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-sales">
          <div class="card-name">
            <h1>Ventas</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="card-info">
            <p>Mes: 50€<img title="Aumento respecto al mes pasado" class="img-up" src="images/up.png" alt="info" /></p>
            <p>A&ntilde;o: 758€<img title="Aumento respecto al año pasado" class="img-up" src="images/up.png" alt="info" /></p>
            <a href="#" class="card-more-info">
              <p>Ver</p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-repairs">
          <div class="card-name">
            <h1>Reparaciones</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="card-info">
            <p>Mes: 3</p>
            <p>A&ntilde;o: 35</p>
            <a href="#" class="card-more-info">
              <p>Ver</p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-expenses">
          <div class="card-name">
            <h1>Gastos</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="card-info">
            <p>Mes: 150€<img title="Decremento respecto al mes pasado" class="img-down" src="images/down.png" alt="info" /></p>
            <p>A&ntilde;o: 1565€<img title="Decremento respecto al año pasado" class="img-down" src="images/down.png" alt="info" /></p>
            <a href="#" class="card-more-info">
              <p>Ver</p>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="report-container">
        <div id="container-title">
          <h2>Informes</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card card-repairs">
        <div class="card-name">
          <h1>Reparaciones</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="card-info">
          <p>Mes: 3</p>
          <p>A&ntilde;o: 35</p>
          <a href="#" class="card-more-info">
            <p>Ver</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div id="footer">
    <p id="footer-text">Hecho con <span style="color: red;">&#x2764;</span> por Bruno D&iacute;az Mart&iacute;n</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estás aplicando las etiquetas `section`, `header` o `aside`, emplea también `footer` en vez de un `div`. Luego, al `footer`, le puedes meter una `class` o un `id` o emplear en el `css` la etiqueta `footer`.

A su vez, te recomiendo mejor el uso de `div`, pues te facilita más las cosas, así como las herramientas de desarrollador (haz clic derecho en la página y pulsa en Inspeccionar Elemento) pues eso te puede ayudar mucho para saber los fallos que vas a ir encontrando, pues, al principio, en mi pantalla, se veía estupendamente (el problema es la carencia de diseño responsive).

Comment: Hola Manuel, te sugiero agregues un ejemplo aplicado al código que muestra el OP, por el formato de tu publicación parece un comentario, revisa [answer], saludos.

Comment: Sí, es un comentario, pero el problema es que todavía la web no me deja hacer comentarios :(

Comment: Las preguntas y respuestas no deben de incluir saludos, despedidas, ni ninguna otra información que no sea necesaria para entender la pregunta / respuesta. Ref. https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior